# Import sound file into Music memos

Tags: iphone, audio, music

Is there a way to import an audio file (of either format) into Music Memos on iOS?

I want to try to utilize the “automatic” drums of the app on some older guitar recordings. From what I can tell, the drum function listens to a memo and tries to play along, so wouldn’t it be neat if we could hand it a recording from another source and tell it “Here, put drums on this”?

I’ve been looking through the iPhone file structure in PhoneView, but I fear I lack the deeper understanding. Otherwise, copying a recording with the right format into where Music memos stores recordings, I imagine one could convince the app that this is a legit memo file. You know?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your music file must be a [.caf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format?wprov=sfti1) file.
2. Open Settings → Music Memos and see what the ‘Use iCloud’ switch is set to.
   You don't need to change it, just keep it in mind for step 5.
3. Find your music file in the Files app, such as in the Downloads folder if it came from Safari.
4. Long press the file and choose Move (or Copy).
5. If the switch in step 2 was on, find Music Memos under ‘iCloud Drive’.
   If the switch was off, find Music Memos under ‘On This iPhone’.
6. Move/copy the file to that location.

This worked for me with a test caf file and iOS 13.5.